# Power output from a buck boost circuit is too low

Tags: power-supply, inductor, boost, buck-boost

Thanks to all who helped on the earlier part of the circuit - that's now fixed and working.

Now the buck boost circuit to drive the LED is working, but it only puts out a very small fraction of the power that it should.

Here is the circuit:

[image]

It is supposed to boost the Vcc from 8V to 12 or 13V to drive the LED at 130-800mA with different R77 resistor values.  Vcc comes from 2 18650 Li ion batteries with sufficient current/power capacity.

With R77 at 4.7ohm, I am supposed to get 130mA across the resistor & through the LEDs, with the feedback voltage at 0.6V.  I actually get a feedback voltage of 0.3V, so 65mA.  (V+ for the led is 10.7V, as indicated.)

When I switch to a lower resistor, V+ and the current stay more or less the same, and the feedback voltage drops to 0.15V (corresponds to roughly 65mA.) (V+ drops slightly to 10.65 or 10.6V.)

I already tried different inductors, but I get more or less similar behavior.

Any ideas what else to try?

Comment: Is the input voltage sagging? Is the inductor saturating?

Comment: Connecting the caps as you did means the current through `R77` is both DC and AC (i.e. the current through the diode, `D14`). That will most probably confuse the feedback loop. You need to make `R77` in series with the load, and those caps parallel across everything (i.e. grounded).

Comment: input voltage is not sagging.  I don't think the inductor is saturating since i tried different ones, including some from standard off-the-shelf china buck booster boards (that worked well with the same batteries and LEDs)

Comment: I will try running the caps parallel across everything... and also check how they were with the china board that worked properly...

Comment: the caps parallel across everything helped a lot.

strangely, the feedback voltage is .68v with the 4.7ohm, then .64v with 2.2ohm, .58v with 1 ohm, and then .45v with .8ohm... the last step is more or less the same current / power through the Led.

Comment: also, I have 3 identical circuits in parallel as I am driving 3 led panels and didn't want to drive them off a single booster.   each has their own booster.  and although I made the same changes to each of them, they are behaving differently.  With 4.7ohm, no.2 is similar (.65v on feedback pin) but no.3 is giving something like 1.1v.  when I switch to the lower 2.2 ohm resistance, they drop to .3v & .4v...